# Rect won't update position when the sprite it is taken from moves

Tags: python, loops, pygame, sprite, rect

```
player_rect = Pfront_n.get_rect()
```

Here 'Pfront_n' is a sprite, and I am getting a rect for that sprite. This is outside of the main loop. When inside the main loop, `print(player_rect)` shows that when my player moves, the rect doesn't follow. My players movement system is a velocity based one, if that makes any difference. How can I have the rect stay around the player?

Following this, I have another similar question...

```
for layer in room2:
        r_x = 0
        for tile in layer:  
            if tile == '2':
                bat_create()    
            if tile == '1':
                screen.blit(grass, (r_x*40, r_y*40))        
            if tile != '0':
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect)
            r_x += 1
        r_y += 1
```

Outside the main loop, I have created a rect for `grass` in the same was as I have for my player. The method I am using in the above code has multiple `grass` blocks appear in positions pre-determined by an array. How can I get the rects for each individual `grass` block?
Fairly Irrelevant Sidenote for Context -The ultimate goal is to use my players rect, and the `grass` rect so my player gets stopped when hitting the `grass`. Any help on either of these questions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Sprite` has no method `get_rect`. Probably `Pfront_n` is a `Surface`. A surface has no position, not, a surface is `blit` at a position onto another surface. The x and y coordinate which is returned by `get_rect()` is (0, 0). But you can set the position. The keyword arguments to `get_rect` are set to the corresponding virtual attribute of `pygame.Rect`. e.g:
(`player_x`, `player_y` is supposed to be the position of the player)

```py
player_rect = Pfront_n.get_rect(topleft = (player_x, player_y))
```

What is `tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect)` supposed to do? `pygame.Rect` is a class.  If you want to append a `pygame.Rect` object, which represents a tile to `tile_rects`, then it has to be:

```py
tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(r_x*40, r_y*40, 40, 40))
```